# Makefile on Eclipse to create filename with date and time

Tags: eclipse, date, time, makefile

How can I in eclipse on a c/c++ project using a makefile (.mk) create a compiled file with the name as the date and time of the build?

Comment: Is this an eclipse question or a makefile question? Are you asking how to configure eclipse or how to write the makefile snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I did this in windows, but it was quite a hack.  The basic idea is to parse the output text from the date and time commands.  The problem is that the date format depends on the regional setting, so you might set up the parsing correct for your system, but if the regional settings change then the parsing is broken.

My solution was to save a backup to `OriginalDateFormat.reg`, modify the regional setting, grab a date string then restore the backup.

This code sets the environment variable `backup_path` according to the date and time; I use it to backup code on every build to a folder with the date/time as it's name. It runs as a pre-build step.

```
@rem --- save a Backup of the date format ---
@reg export "HKCU\Control Panel\International" OriginalDateFormat.reg /y > nul

@rem --- Set my date format so I can parse it (warning impacts whole OS!) ---
@echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00          >  NewDateFormat.reg
@echo.                                              >>  NewDateFormat.reg
@echo [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International] >> NewDateFormat.reg
@echo "sShortDate"="yyyyMMdd"                       >> NewDateFormat.reg
@rem     - note: tried adjusting the time format but didn't work.
@rem    @echo "sShortTime"="HH:mm:ss"               >> NewDateFormat.reg
@rem    @echo "sTimeFormat"="HH:mm:ss"              >> NewDateFormat.reg
@reg import NewDateFormat.reg  2> nul

@rem --- define backup folder using date and time, and      ---
@set backup_path=%2archive\%date%-%time:~0,2%h%time:~3,2%m%time:~6,5%
@set backup_path=%backup_path: =0%
@rem - note that the hour in backup_path may not have a zero for AM times.
@rem - use the foolowing to replace space with 0 %backup_path: =0%
@rem - todo: do replace space on backup_path here!

@rem --- restore date format ---
@reg import OriginalDateFormat.reg  2> nul
@del OriginalDateFormat.reg NewDateFormat.reg
```

Side effects of doing this is that if any registry settings are changed or deleted while this batch runs, those changes could be lost.  It's a small fraction of time, and those settings are primarily only ever changed by the user.

If 2 separate threads are doing this kind of trickery though, all bets are off... one thread could accidentally grab a backup while it was modified, and thus could restore the modified settings leaving the changes in place.